# Codeigniter sorting page content

Tags: php, codeigniter, sorting

I use php with codeigniter for my website. Here I have some lots (models) which I want sort by time, category etc (for each sort type I have link on page). Now I have next code but it's not working (page is not sorting). Here's my controller:

```
<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Gamezone extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
       if (sizeof($_GET) > 0) {
           $sortType = $_GET['sortType'];
       } else {
           $sortType = 0;
       }
       $this->lang->load('auth', $this->language_lib->detect());
       $data['aukcion'] = 'Gamezone';
       $this->load->model('auctions_model');
       $data['auct'] = $this->auctions_model->game_zones($sortType);
       $this->load->view('/common/header_view',$data);
       $this->load->view('gamezone_view',$data);
       $this->load->view('/common/footer_view',$data);
   }
}
```

Here's method game_zones($sortType) from my model:

```
public function game_zones($type) {
    switch ($type) {
        case 1:
            $this->db->order_by('start_time', 'desc');      
            break;
        case 2:
            $this->db->order_by('category', 'desc');
            break;
        case 3:
            $this->db->order_by('genre', 'desc');
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    $query = $this->db->get_where('ay_lots', array('game_zone' => 1));
    $result = $query->result();
    return $result;
}
```

I do ajax request to index to provide sorting like this:

```
function sortAuctions(sortType) {
   $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: '/gamezone/index',
       data: { 'sortType' : sortType },
       success: function(data) {

           window.location = '/gamezone';
       }
   }); 
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax call is redirecting after it receives a successful response.

You appear to have your view set up to handle sorting and you most likely want to redirect to your index action with the query parameters indicating sort. An ajax approach, as it appears you are attempting with your javascript, would generally take some sort of api response or stripped down rendering of the html view and manipulate the dom to update the response.